# Unable to download groovy.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

Any help appreciated.

I'm new to Maven. I got the below command from tutorials point

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.tutorialpoint.app -DartifactId=camel-first-app -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-spring -DinteractiveMode=false
```

it is failing with below error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
Downloading: 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.981s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 14 23:11:42 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: I tried the same command as above and it works fine. Could it be a network issue?

Comment: Some network problem: `1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar from central failed: Connection reset -`....

Comment: Yes it seems so from the description in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant error is pointing to a connection problem:

> Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3
>   from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):  GET request
>   of: org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar from central
>   failed: Connection reset

The command which you posted actually runs fine on my machine. If you execute this maven command and you do not have the Groovy libraries yet, you will see that it actually downloads the following files:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar

It might be that you have only access to the internet via a proxy. In this case you will need to setup a proxy in the Maven configuration.

This [blog](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/) here contains a fairly good description on how to setup a proxy for Maven, so that Maven can access the repository libraries.

Another option to tackle your problem would be to manually download this file using your browser:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar

And then install it in your repository manually using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=org.codehaus.groovy \
    -DartifactId=groovy -Dversion=1.8.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

But normally you should not have to do this manual download + installation. Maven should be doing this for you.

Comment: Super!! Thanks. This worked for me. I've tried through the link to blog for property file change.